# How to download the all the requests in postman collections as one folder??

Tags: postman

When I do export , all the requests are downloaded in single json file.
But I want all the requests in postman to be downloaded as single folder so that I can zip and send someone rather than sharing the link.

My postman version is Version 6.2.1 .

Comment: Hi @manyDoubts if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and up-voting it. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible. You can only share it as a JSON file, or directly make one collection visible in another. Doc link: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/collections/sharing_collections